# Deriving instances for custom class for types in Haskell

Tags: haskell, generic-programming

I'm trying to reduce the amount of boilerplate in Copilot.

In a recent version, we added structs, and using them requires declaring two instances. An example from [Copilot's repo](https://github.com/Copilot-Language/copilot-testing/blob/8e3a0b9138348e8e8af031a0d3e3cbe592be3e25/src/Copilot/Testing/Datatypes.hs) follows.

For the datatype:

```
data TestStruct = TestStruct
  { i :: Field "i" Int8
  }
```

We need the instances:

```
instance Struct TestStruct where
  typename _ = "teststruct"
  toValues t = [ Value Int8 (i t) ]

instance Typed TestStruct where
  typeOf = Struct (TestStruct { i = Field 0 })
```

I would like to make this easier to use by generating the instances automatically.

I've been looking into Generics and I've used Template Haskell before, but things have changed a lot over the last few years. Many packages and recommended solutions are now outdated, and it would take me months to go through the last 10 years of papers and libraries only to find out later that they are not in use anymore. I'm having trouble understanding what the compiler can already do automatically, what generics extension or package I should use (if any), and generally finding an up-to-date approach that works and will continue to work.

What would be the best way to generate instances for those classes automatically? (I'd like to avoid TH if possible, but I understand that it may not be possible as of today.)

Comment: I don’t have time to elaborate this into a full answer, but the technique I’d typically use here is to write `Struct` and `Typed` with `default` methods in terms of `Generic`, which allows using `DeriveGeneric`+`DeriveAnyClass` to write `deriving (Generic, Struct, Typed)` (or `deriving stock (Generic)`+`deriving anyclass (Struct, Typed)` with explicit `DerivingStrategies`)

Answer (score 0):

As in most cases, the simplest implementation can be made just from consulting the [`GHC.Generics` documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/GHC-Generics.html).

The approach described by @Jon Purdy in the comment is valuable, and I'm basing this answer off it.

## Deriving `Typed`

Simple enough - implementations for producing default values for base types and generic types already exist. [`data-default-class`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-default-class-0.1.2.0/docs/Data-Default-Class.html) seems fit-for-purpose, though that's not a recommendation: I just picked one of the first Hoogle results.

```hs
default typeOf :: (Typeable a, Struct a, Default a) => Typed a
typeOf = Struct def
```

It's then possible to just derive `Default` and `Typed` to get a good implementation.

The above requires a `Default` instance for `Field`, but it's almost obvious

```hs
instance (Default f) => Default (Field n f) where
  def = Field def
```

## Deriving `Struct`

This is the trickier one, since it requires touching the guts of generics. However, looking at the specific use case of Copilot, it seems like we can ignore a lot of possible things (like multiple constructors, etc).

The longer form of this answer might also say to give recursive instances for things like `D1` and `C1`, if they turned out to be necessary.

### Deriving `typename`

Not necessary - just use the [type constructor metadata](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/GHC-Generics.html#t:D1). If you *really* want to, define a class

```hs
class TypeName' f where
  typename' :: f p -> String
```

but it would only need a single instance for `D1`.

### Deriving `toValues`

This will need the [constructor argument representation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/GHC-Generics.html#t:S1). Define a class

```hs
class ToValues' a f where
  toValues' :: Proxy a -> f p -> [Value a]
```

`a` is a class argument because it mechanically has to be, and `Proxy` is a function argument because otherwise GHC complains about `a` not appearing - and there are no fundeps to help solve that problem.

Representation of multiple fields is done through the product representation `:*:` combining multiple fields. This means there needs to be an instance for the singleton field `S1` and an instance for the product of two subinstances.

Defining the instances is not too hard

```hs
instance (Typed c, KnownSymbol fieldName) => ToValues' a (S1 m (Rec0 (Field fieldName c))) where
  toValues' p (M1 (K1 field)) = [Value (typeOf @c) field]
```

The above instance gives a singleton for each field, and the product can perform concatenation

```hs
instance (ToValues' a l, ToValues' a r) => ToValues' a (l :*: r) where
  toValues' p (l :*: r) = toValues' p l ++ toValues' p r
```

### The instance

I use type unification `~` here for type-level pattern matching.

```hs
default typename :: (Generic a, Rep a ~ D1 ('MetaData typeName m p nt) f), KnownSymbol typeName) => a -> String
typename _ = toLower (symbolVal (Proxy @typeName))

default toValues :: (Generic a, Rep a ~ D1 m1 (C1 m2 f), ToValues' a f) => a -> [Value a]
toValues a = toValues' (Proxy @a) fields
  where (M1 (M1 fields)) = (from a)
```

`toLower` is just a `String`-lowercasing function, though you'll have to define it. `symbolVal` gives the `String` for a type-level `Symbol`.

The `toValues` code assumes there is a single data constructor, by constraining `Rep a` to be of the form `D1 _ (C1 _ _)`.

As before, it would now be possible to just derive `Generic` and `Struct` to get this useful instance.